# Does the prime sequence satisfy $p_n+p_m \le p_{n+m} < p_n p_m$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I did some experiments in SAGE and it seems like the prime sequence $p_n$ satisfies:

$$p_n+p_m \le p_{n+m} < p_n p_m$$
for $(n,m) \neq (1,1)$.

For $n=1$ the last inequality is [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Here is some SAGE code to test this for some primes:

```
lp = list(primes(10000))
for n in range(len(lp)):
    for m in range(len(lp)):
        pn = lp[n]
        pm = lp[m]
        pnm = nth_prime(n+m+2)
        print pn*pm>=pnm,pnm>=pn+pm, n+1,m+1,n+m+2,pn,pm,pn*pm,pnm
```

Is this something known ( if it is true)? And if so, how does one prove or disprove it, are there heuristics?

Comment: WLOG, we can assume $n\le m$ implying $p_n\le p_m$

Comment: IMO for larger $n,m$ it should be possible to use the inequaltities
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities
$n (\ln (n \ln n) - 1) < p_n < n \ln (n \ln n)$ for $n \ge 6$,
and the remaining $n,m$ with direct computation.

Comment: We have the inequality $p_{n+1}>2p_n$, but if your conjecture is true, then letting $m=n$ implies that $2p_{n+1}<p_{2n+1}$ for $n>1$ which is definitely a tighter upper bound. Doing some tests, however, I think a stronger inequality is that $$2p_{n+1}\le p_{2n+1}-1\tag{$n>1$}$$

Comment: @gammatester maybe a similar conjecture than that the OP proposed is feasible for Ramanujan primes (I say write a similar inequality involving Ramanujan primes $\mathcal{R}_k$ instead of prime numbers $p_k$). Isn't required a response I did this comment just to provide feedback about your comment.

Comment: The first part of the inequality holds for $1\le n\le m\le 2\cdot 10^4$ with the exception $m=n=1$. I am currently checking the second part in the same range, yet no counterexample.

Comment: No counterexample for the second part in the given range.

Comment: @Peter how do you test for such large numbers?

Comment: The numbers are not actually large. I use the PARI/GP-calculator.

Comment: gammatester's suggestion might already work.

Comment: @Peter imho, $2\times10^4$ is already large enough :)

Comment: @gammatester: I don't see how to use the inequalities you mentioned. Maybe you could write an answer?

Comment: Though it's probably hard to prove, the first inequality seems pretty intuitive. If you write it as $p_{n+m}-p_m\ge p_m$, it basically says the primes are closest together near $1$, so if you want to find a stretch of the number line with $m$ primes, the smallest stretch is $1,2,\ldots,p_m$.

Comment: Here a sketch for the first. Let $f(n)=\ln(n\ln n))$. This function is strictly increasing and $p_n < n f(n), \; n>6$. Therefore with $n>m$  we have
$$p_n+p_m <nf(n)+mf(m) < nf(n)+mf(n) = (n+m)f(n) < (n+m)f(n+m) \le p_{n+m}$$

Comment: It is only a partial answer for the first inequality. The second seems harder.

Comment: @gammatester: But $p_{n+m}<(n+m)f(n+m)$...

Comment: Correct, I guess we had to use more properties of $f(n)$ to show
$nf(n)+mf(m) \le (n+m)(f(n+m)-1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left inequality is equivalent to the [Second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture).

The [k-tuple conjecutre](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html), AKA First Hardy-Littlewood conjecture is the statement that the density of every Prime Constellation can be computed using a single general formula. If it is true, then there are infinitely many twin primes, also infinitely many prime tuples of form $(p, p+4)$, $(p, p+6)$, $(p, p+2, p+6, p+8)$, etc. Note that it does not imply the prime tuple $(p, p+2, p+4)$ is infinite, which is not true.

If k-tuple conjecture is true, then Second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture is not true. $\pi(3159)=446$, but there may be $447$-tuple primes spanning $3159$ integers. Such tuple is not yet discovered, but the formula in k-tuple conjecture suggests that the first such tuple is likely to be between $1.5\times10^{174}$ and $2.2\times10^{1198}$.

---

For right inequality, WLOG assume that $m \le n$. Then for $10 \le n$ and $3 \le m$, we can apply the inequality mentioned by @gammatester. $$p_{m+n}\le p_{2n}<2n\ln{(2n\ln{2n})}<4n{(\ln(n\ln n)-1)}<4p_n\le p_mp_n$$

For $n<10$, one can check all the cases manually. For $m=1$, it is Bertrand's Postulate. For $m=2$, it is proving $p_{n+2}<3p_n$. [It is known that](https://doi.org/10.3792/pja/1195570997) if $k\ge25$, then there exists a prime between $k$ and $1.2k$. It is trivial corollary that $p_{n+2}<1.2^3p_n<3p_n$ if $n>10$, especially since $p_{10}=29>25$.