# Conjectured inequality: $\frac{p_{2n+1}-1}{2}\geqslant p_{n+1}+2(n+1)^{2/(n-1)}+\frac12\log_{4}^2(n-6)\qquad(n>6)$

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, logarithms, conjectures, upper-lower-bounds

I was inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795345/does-the-prime-sequence-satisfy-p-np-m-le-p-nm-p-n-p-m) to look at some prime numbers and see if I can find a bound.

In the post, a conjecture was made with variables $m$ and $n$ such that $(m,n)\neq (1,1)$ respectively. I was able to prove that if it was true, then $m=n$ would imply a tighter upper bound for $p_{n+1}$. A current upper bound for $p_{n+1}$ is $2p_n$, but the OP's conjecture would imply that $2p_{n+1}<p_{2n+1}$ which is tighter and better than the inequality, $p_{n+1}<2p_n$.

Doing some tests, I thought that a better inequality would be that $2p_{n+1}\le p_{2n+1}-1$, but then I decided to do some *more* tests and I came up with a conjecture.

> > **Conjecture:**
>
> $$\begin{align}\frac{p_{2n+1}-1}{2}&\geqslant p_{n+1}+2(n+1)^{2/(n-1)}\underbrace{+\,\frac 12\log_4^2(n-6)}_{\text{recent edit}}\tag{$n>6$} \\ \text{with equal}&\text{ity iff $n=7$.}\end{align}$$

Can this be proven/disproven?

---

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** For a tighter bound, I added the term ${}^1/{}_2\log_{4}^{2}(n-6)^\dagger$ to the RHS (*Right-Hand Side*).

---

> <sub>${}^\dagger$By $\log_b^2(x)$, I mean $\big(\log_b(x)\big)^2$.</sub>

Comment: @YuriyS My mistake. Instead of $p_{2n+1}$ on the RHS, it was supposed to be $p_{n+1}$. I changed it this time :)

Comment: Oh, I see. How far have you checked this inequality? (i.e. it works at least for $n \leq N$ where $N$ is?)

Comment: Well, I did for $n\le 30$ but I am doing more. I am feeling confident that it must be true at least for $n > 30$.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it works for any $n>6$, but the inequality is not very tight http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%7BPrime%5B2n%2B1%5D,N%5B1%2B2+Prime%5Bn%2B1%5D+%2B4+(n%2B1)%5E(2%2F(n-1))%5D%7D,%7Bn,7,100%7D%5D

Comment: @YuriyS I had no idea you could *do* that on Wolfram|Alpha!!

Comment: Why not simplify using $2(n+1)^{2/(n-1)} < 5$? Then it is just $p_{2n+1}\ge2p_{n+1}+11$

Comment: @didgogns well, given the information **YuriyS** provided, I decided to add $\log_{1/4}(n-6)^2$ to the RHS. It should be tighter now.

Comment: @didgogns so this would mean that $p_{2n+1}\geqslant 2p_{n+1}+\log_{1/4}(n-6)^2+11$, right? Unless there exists an upper bound for the $\log$ term.

Comment: The logarithmic term seems arbitrary, where did it come from?

Comment: @YuriyS I just looked to see if I could make it tighter, and it turns out I could. I am not a prime-number expert; I am just a kid who enjoys math(s), especially the prime numbers.

Comment: We have $(\log_{1/x}y)^2=(\log_xy)^2$ for any $x,y>0$; so why use a fractional base?

Comment: @JohnBentin I never heard of that rule. Thanks for telling me :)

Comment: @user477343 John's rule follows easily from $$\log_{1/x}(y)=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(1/x)}=-\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(x)}=-\log_x(y)$$

Comment: @Peter thank you for telling me. Also, for $n=9$ and $n=11$, the inequality *does* hold according to wolfram alpha. I will show you the values shortly.

Comment: @Peter type this into wolfram alpha: **Table[{Prime[2n+1],N[1+2 Prime[n+1] +4 (n+1)^(2/(n-1))+(log_4(n-6))^2]},{n,7,200}]** and it should give you the first $200$ values of $n$ from $n=7$ with the LHS values in the left column and RHS values in the right column of a table. Notice that the RHS values are *less than* the LHS values. Is there a mistake I didn't write? I defined $\log_b^2(x)$ as $\big(\log_b(x)\big)^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78020/discussion-between-peter-and-user477343).

Comment: @Peter well obviously Wolfram Alpha is getting something wrong... nice job :)

Comment: @Peter there was a $2$, but I thought writing the $2$ was a typo as in ther wolfram alpha link, there was a $4$. It turns out, the $4$ was not a typo $-$ I just multiplied both sides by $2$ and added $1$. Which means I should add $$\frac12\log_4^2(n-6)\;\verb|instead of|\; \log_4^2(n-6)$$ **Now** it should work :)

Comment: @user477343   The conjecture is true for $n\le 90\ 000$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using equations $(11)$ and $(12)$ from [here](https://docserv.uni-duesseldorf.de/servlets/DerivateServlet/Derivate-28284/pdfa-1b.pdf), for $n\ge688683$, $$\frac12p_{2n+1}-p_{n+1}>f(n)$$ where $$f(n)=\frac{2n+1}2\left(\ln(2n+1)+\ln\ln(2n+1)-1-\frac{\ln\ln(2n+1)-2.1}{\ln(2n+1)}\right)-(n+1)\left(\ln(n+1)+\ln\ln(n+1)-1-\frac{\ln\ln(n+1)-2}{\ln(n+1)}\right)$$ and clearly $f(n)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+2(n+1)^{\frac{2}{n-1}}+\frac{\ln^2(n-6)}{\ln^24}\right)$ is monotonically increasing as the $x\ln x$ terms in $f$ dominate. It can be computationally verified that the inequality holds for $n<688683$.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Congratulations on $13$k reputation! :D $(+1)\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: Thanks! Though the 13k has been rounded so I need about 30 more :)